# Vue выгрузка таблицы в excel

Tags: javascript, vue.js, excel, export

Всех приветствую. Подскажите каким образом можно выгрузить всю таблицу Vue в Excel файл.
Нашел несколько библиотек, но там выгрузка json данных.

Comment: А как выгрузить не-Vue таблицу в excel?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, поэтому и создал вопрос. Нашел выгрузку данных. Но таблицы отрисована сложного вида.